# Enable textbox when checkbox ticked - php

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I am trying to enable the textbox when checkbox is checked and my coding do like what I want. When submit button clicked it will check the entire form and give error information for every empty field that not been filled and keep the rest information remain to every field that been filled. The problem is, when the checkbox is checked, textbox enabled and been filled, after pressing the submit button (when all required field not completed), the textbox will become disabled with value remained.

Below is coding that I currently use :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chklist" onchange="document.getElementById('txtOthers').disabled = !this.checked;" <?php if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']) && isset($_POST['chklist'])) echo "checked" ?> /> OTHERS : 
    <input style="width: 130px;" type="textbox" id="txtOthers" name="txtOthers" disabled value="<?php echo $others;?>" />
```

Comment: What JavaScript have you written so far to accomplish these things?

Comment: Please show javascript/jquery code that you have use, it's difficult to guess with present info

Comment: @wogsland I only put the `onchange="document.getElementById('txtOthers').disabled = !this.checked;"` in the `checkbox` to enable and disable the `textbox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to do so :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chklist" id="checkbox" <?php if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']) && isset($_POST['chklist'])) echo "checked" ?> /> OTHERS : 
<input style="width: 130px;" type="textbox" id="txtOthers" name="txtOthers" disabled value="<?php echo $others;?>" />

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#checkbox").change(function(){
        if ($('input.checkbox_check').is(':checked')) {
           $(#txtOthers).show();
        }else{
           $(#txtOthers).hide();
        }
    });
    $("form").submit(function() {
        $("#txtOthers").prop('disabled', true);
     });
});
```

Comment: hello, thank you for the answer. I tried it and still the same result. The entire page is actually refreshing when submit button is clicked, so it will make the `textbox` disabled again. Is there any way I can do something like `if (isset($_POST['chklist'])){ //Do something to enabled textbox }`

Comment: you can add one more thing submit form through jQuery.ajax. it will avoid refreshing page.
$("#submit").click(function(){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(result){
//do your stuff after form submit
} }
});

Comment: delete this code: $("form").submit(function() {
        $("#txtOthers").prop('disabled', true);
     });